# Java PriorityQueue implementation: Why Object[] queue instead of E[] queue? What's the purpose of "key" in siftUp/siftDownComparable?

Tags: heap, java

I'm studying the [JDK implementation of PriorityQueue](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/PriorityQueue.java#PriorityQueue.siftDownComparable%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%29).

1) The entire queue is stored in

```
 transient Object[] queue;
```

Why not declare the array using the generic E? (Instead, there's a lot of casting E to objects in the class.)

2) The first line of the siftUpComparable/siftDownComparable methods is

```
    Comparable<? super E> key = (Comparable<? super E>)x;
```

Is this a guard clause to verify that x is comparable? (Otherwise, why not just use x directly?)

Here's the entire method:

```
private void siftDownComparable(int k, E x) {
    Comparable<? super E> key = (Comparable<? super E>)x;
    int half = size >>> 1;        // loop while a non-leaf
    while (k < half) {
        int child = (k << 1) + 1; // assume left child is least
        Object c = queue[child];
        int right = child + 1;
        if (right < size &&
            ((Comparable<? super E>) c).compareTo((E) queue[right]) > 0)
            c = queue[child = right];
        if (key.compareTo((E) c) <= 0)
            break;
        queue[k] = c;
        k = child;
    }
    queue[k] = key;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You cannot instantiate an array of a generic type without having a reference to the Class of the object. See JavaDevil's comment below for an example. However, by creating an array of Object's instead, there's is no requirement to feed an instance of the Class to the PriorityQueue.

```
E[] array = new E[10]; // won't compile
```

2) A PriorityQueue can sort its elements either by a Comparable's object `compareTo()` method or using a Comparator for objects that are not necessarily Comparable. The siftDownComparable method is only invoked if a Comparator was not provided when the PriorityQueue was created. Since the type parameter does not stipulate that `<E extends Comparable>`, you need to cast it explicitly. Here's the siftDown() method.

```
private void siftDown(int k, E x) {
    if (comparator != null)
        siftDownUsingComparator(k, x);
    else
        siftDownComparable(k, x);
}
```

Comment: _You cannot instantiate an array of a generic type_ Is not quite true, yes what you have written won't compile, but you can instantiate a generic array using `(T[]) Array.newInstance(Class<T>)`, but this requires you to pass in the class